# Where is a mistake in my task? The test does not skip any further

Tags: python-3.x

Zenyk recorded losses daily throughout
n
days, but suddenly noticed that he had made a mistake and lost data on enemy losses on one of the days. However, Zenyk knows the total number of losses
y
, as well as the fact that every day the enemy lost a positive number of soldiers. In this way he can reconstruct the number of enemy casualties for that day, provided that Zenic has not made another mistake in his records. Help Zenic recover the number of enemy casualties for a day for which there is no data. If Zenyk made an additional mistake in the notebook, display Another mistake!

Incoming data
The first line contains two integers
n
and
x
— the number of days in which Zenyk recorded statistics, as well as the total losses of the enemy.
In the next line is given
n - 1
numbers
ai
, separated by blanks — data on daily enemy losses according to Zenik's notebook.
Output data
Output one number - the number of enemy casualties on the day Zenyk forgot to record the data.

If Zenyk made another mistake in his notebook and the data in the notebook is contradictory, then output Another mistake!.

```
n, x = map(int, input().split())
for i in range(n-1):
    a = list(map(int, input().split()))
    b = sum(a)
    c = x - b
    print(c)
if x < b:
    print('Another mistake!')
```

Input:
1 100000
Output:
100000
Input:
2, 10
2
Output: 8
Input:
2 15
47
Output:
'Another mistake!'

This is my code, but the test does not skip any further!
Can you suggest what is wrong and correct my code for this task

Comment: Can you suggest sample inputs and corresponding expected outputs?

Comment: Added to the description

Comment: It looks like you get inputs twice per run in your script, make sure your updated description reflects that too.

Comment: Yes there twice

Comment: The description does not reflect them as it should be

Comment: You can help with the assignment?